# parallel process with popen

Tags: php, popen

I need to download files from many web servers and then do somethigs. Some files are big. Each downloads it's independent from another so I want to do in parallel.

So I write the following scripts:

**test.php**

```
$urls = [
    'url1', 'url2', 'url3'
];

foreach($urls as $url){
    popen("php download.php --url=" . $url, "w");
}
```

**download.php**

```
$options = getopt(null, ["url:"]);
$url = $options["url"];
// do somethings - This loop is just for testing purposes
for($i = 0; $i <= 1000000000; $i++){
    $i;
}
print parse_url($url)["host"];
```

When i run `php test.php` console show me a sequencial output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `exec("php download.php --url=" . escapeshellarg ($url) . " &");`, or use gnu parallel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the best solution.

[Pool](http://php.net/manual/es/class.pool.php) was covered all my requirements. Pool-worker is a software design pattern in such Pool is a container and has many Workers (Process waiting for tasks). tasks are added to the pool and then, each worker take a task to exec.

By the other hand, I think that [Python's implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) is better that PHP's implementation of Pool-worker pattern than PHP.

Answer (score 0):

if you want them run in async use this, run each in the background.

```
popen("php download.php --url=" . $url . " &", "w");
```

demo:

```
<?php
$urls = ['www.baidu.com', 'github.com', 'stackoverflow.com'];
foreach($urls as $url)
{
  var_dump(popen("ping -c4 " . $url . " &", "w"));
  echo "dddd\n";
}
```

output:

```
ei@localhost:~$ php test.php
resource(4) of type (stream)
dddd
resource(5) of type (stream)
dddd
resource(6) of type (stream)
dddd
ei@localhost:~$ PING www.a.shifen.com (61.135.169.121) 56(84) bytes of data.
PING github.com (192.30.255.112) 56(84) bytes of data.
PING stackoverflow.com (151.101.193.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 61.135.169.121: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=5.53 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=75.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.255.112: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=262 ms
64 bytes from 61.135.169.121: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=5.24 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=74.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.255.112: icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=262 ms
64 bytes from 61.135.169.121: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=30.4 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=107 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.255.112: icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=260 ms
64 bytes from 61.135.169.121: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=20.0 ms

--- www.a.shifen.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.244/15.311/30.413/10.578 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69: icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=95.3 ms

--- stackoverflow.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 74.732/88.154/107.341/13.857 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.255.112: icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=256 ms

--- github.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 256.064/260.310/262.474/2.606 ms
```

Comment: I suspected it but how should run download.php process for each url in parallel way?

Comment: Here I thought they are also in parallel apart the start time. For the subprocess last very little time, so they seems run in sequence.

Comment: Yes, I throught too but I was wrong. I have added a loop and keeps runs sequencially. See my edit